# Gradle cannot find plugin declared in buildscript

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to factor out common Gradle tasks in a reusable file. Here is an excerpt of a build-root.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    // Repository declaration
    ext {
        isSnapshot = version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")
        repos = {
            def mavenRepo = { repoName, repoUrl ->
                maven {
                    credentials {
                        username System.env.<some env var>
                        password System.env.<some env var>
                    }
                    name repoName
                    url repoUrl
                }
            }
            mavenLocal()
            mavenRepo('repo1', 'https://repo1.url')
            mavenRepo('repo2', 'https://repo2.url')
            mavenRepo('repo3', 'https://repo3.url')
        }
    }

    // Versions and libraries declaration
    ext {
        versions = [
                ... some stuff
                // Gradle
                gradleRelease           : '2.8.1',
                ... more stuff
        ]
        libs = [
                ... some stuff
                // Gradle
                gradleRelease           : "net.researchgate:gradle-release:$versions.gradleRelease",
                ... more stuff
        ]
    }

    repositories repos
    dependencies {
        classpath libs.gradleRelease
    }
    apply plugin: 'net.researchgate.release'
}
... more common stuff
```

The idea is for subprojects to apply from that file and get all the goodies from it.

On the "apply plugin" line I get the following error - > Plugin with id 'net.researchgate.release' not found.

I printed the libs.gradleRelease string, it looks fine: net.researchgate:gradle-release:2.8.1

We are currently using Gradle 5.2.1, but I also tried 6.0.1 - same error. Any ideas why it can't find the plugin? BTW, this is not exclusive to this particular plugin, I tried others and still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

After pulling whatever was left of my hair and banging my head against the wall, I came across this => https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-include-buildscript-block-from-external-gradle-script/7016

Relevant comment from @Peter_Niederwieser:

"*Secondly, externalizing a build script block into a script plugin isn’t supported. (It’s a tough problem, and can’t think of a good way to implement this.) You may have to live with some duplication, at least for the time being. Remember that dependencies specified in a project’s ‘buildscript’ block are visible to all subprojects. Hence, as long as you don’t need dependencies to be available in a script plugin, you just need to declare them in the root project’s build script.*"

Which is exactly what I was trying to do. I'm not going to curse here...